# Is there any way to develop a Java 1.5 application using Cucumber-JVM?

Tags: java, java-6, java-5, cucumber-jvm

Cucumber-JVM has dependencies on Java 1.6

My client's application runs on Java 1.5 and this can't be changed at the moment

Does anyone know a way to use Cucumber-JVM to exercise my client's application?

Comment: A program written for 1.5 should run fine under 1.6

Comment: Yes, but I can't change the deployed version of Java on my client's application servers.

Comment: Does it have to be tested on their servers?  If so, can you deploy an additional JRE on their server(s)?  ...I suppose there are dangers not testing in the target JRE...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also posted this question on the Cukes mailing list (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cukes) where I got a response from Aslak Hellesøy (CUcumber's creator):

Me: 
Is there any *reasonable* way to use Cucumber-JVM, built under Java 1.6, to develop a Java application that must run on JRE 1.5?

Aslak Hellesøy: 
Short answer: No.
Long answer: Try it and share the problems you experience, then we can talk about whether it's possible to work around them.